# Calabi-Yau manifolds and polygonal linkage configuration spaces: related?

Tags: reference-request, complex-manifolds, linkage

I was reading about [Calabi-Yau manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi-Yau_manifold), about which I know little, and was wondering
if these (or related complex manifolds, perhaps [K3 surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K3_manifold)) can be viewed as configuration
spaces (or [moduli spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moduli_space)) of articulated polygonal linkages, say with fixed edge lengths and
vertex joints?  This question is a shot in the dark; apologies for its naiveté.  But it might help
me understand complex manifolds if I can view them as polygon configuration spaces.

Any references in this general direction would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An illustrative example: *the moduli space $M$ of regular pentagons with edges of unit length*. This embeds as an open, dense subset of a compact complex surface $\bar{M}$ with a canonical Kaehler form.  This surface, a 4-fold blow-up of $\mathbb{CP}^2$, is not Calabi-Yau (trivial canonical bundle) but Fano (ample anticanonical bundle).

The compactified regular pentagon space $\bar{M}$ is the space of 5-tuples of unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with centre of mass zero, modulo the diagonal action of $SO(3)$. Since we remember the order of these vectors, typical points represent regular pentagons with a distinguished vertex ("start here") and adjacent edge ("go this way"). There are also points which represent an equilateral triangle together with a pair of antipodal points, and these non-pentagon points form ten 2-spheres in $\bar{M}$.

$\bar{M}$ has a natural symplectic structure, for which the ten 2-spheres are Lagrangian. Take the unique area-form on $S^2$, invariant under $SO(3)$, of total area 1 and inducing the complex orientation of $S^2=\mathbb{CP}^1$. The moment map $S^2\to \mathfrak{so}(3)^\ast \cong \mathbb{R}^3$ for the $SO(3)$-action is just the inclusion of $S^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$. The product $(S^2)^5$ carries the product symplectic form, again $SO(3)$-invariant, with moment map $\mu(x_1,\dots,x_5)=x_1+\dots + x_5\in \mathbb{R}^3$. The symplectic quotient $\mu^{-1}(0)/SO(3)$ is just $\bar{M}$.

The action of $SO(3)=PU(2)$ respects the complex structure of $(\mathbb{CP}^1)^5$, and $\bar{M}$ inherits a complex structure by Kaehler reduction. It turns out to be isomorphic as a Kaehler surface to a blow up of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ at four special points with a Fano Kaehler form (but I haven't thought through which points). See Seidel's [Lectures on 4-dimensional Dehn twists](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309012), ex. 1.10.  There's a natural action of the icosahedral group, permuting the $x_i$.

If one wanted pentagons defined by some other linear equation, say $a_1x_1+\dots + a_5x_5=0$, one would give the $S^2$-factors areas $a_i$.

One can also interpret $\bar{M}$ as an algebro-geometric (GIT) quotient of $(\mathbb{CP}^1)^5$ by $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$. The quotient happens to be the Deligne-Mumford (or Grothendieck-Knudsen) compactification $\bar{M}_{0,5}(\mathbb{C})$ of configurations of five points on $\mathbb{CP}^1$. The real points $\bar{M}_{0,5}(\mathbb{R})$, the fixed points of an anti-holomorphic involution of $\bar{M}$, are also interesting: their connected components are polyhedral and are copies of the 2-dimensional [Stasheff associahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associahedron) (a.k.a. pentagon).

**References:**

F. Kirwan, [Cohomology of quotients in symplectic and algebraic geometry](http://books.google.com/books?id=4wfZBnlSaJ0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=kirwan+cohomology+of+quotients&source=bl&ots=WhidvP7PUy&sig=4VbvWVflmsmYZ0F7PrdpO4-G1hg&hl=en&ei=C_aATYuYBovmsQP_g_SSBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).

J.-C. Hausmann and A. Knutson, [Polygon spaces and Grassmannians](http://arxiv.org/pdf/dg-ga/9602012v1).

Comment: Thank you for this erudite and instructive reply!
I've studied the space of unit pentagons through a nice
article in the
_American Mathematical Monthly_ by
Don Shimamoto and Catherine Vanderwaart
("Spaces of polygons in the plane and Morse theory."
Volume 112, pages 289-310, 2005).
But I was unaware of the connection to complex manifolds.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Tim's example has been generalised somewhat by Kapovich and Millson. The space $\mathcal{M}(\mathbf{r})$ of $n$-gons in $\mathbb{E}^3$ with a fixed vector $\mathbf{r}\in\mathbb{R}_+^n$ of side lengths carries the structure of a complex-analytic space with at worst quadratic singularities. This is because $\mathcal{M}(\mathbf{r})$ is a weighted symplectic quotient of the Kähler manifold $(S^2)^n$ by $SO(3)$.

Reference: Michael Kapovich and John J. Millson, [*The symplectic geometry of polygons in Euclidean space*](https://doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214459218). J. Differential Geom. Volume 44, Number 3 (1996), 479-513.